# Perspective view matrix for Y-down coordinate system

Tags: opengl, 3d, perspectivecamera

I have this little toy graphics library in rust I tinker with to learn OpenGL. I initially intended it to do only low-res 2D stuff on it, so I set up the coordinate system for pixel-space orthographic rendering, a system with (0, 0) at the top-left corner of the screen that allows sprites to be "snapped" to pixels for an 8/16-bit style.

Now I'm thinking it would be fun to add a perspective camera to render the sprites in perspective as a sort of paper-doll theater thing, sort of inverse 2.5D, world is 3D but characters are 2D.

So I use the excellent tutorial here:
https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera

Great stuff, but the algorithm calls for deriving from the up-vector [0, 1, 0], so my world renders upside down (since my "up" is [0, -1, 0]). If I do set the "up" as [0, -1, 0] I instead get the X-axis extending from right to left, as if negating "up" rotates 180° around the Z-axis, which again isn't what I want.

Is it at all possible to do a perspective camera view matrix with a typical orthographic world Y-down coordinate system, and how would that be done practically using e.g. glm?

Comment: I attempted to trick it by creating a left-handed view matrix with an [0, -1, 0] up vector using glm::look_at_lh() (in rust, I assume the correpsponding function exists in C++ glm as well). This, however left the screen completely blank for some reason. I thought using a left-handed matrix would merely mirror around the vertical axis?

Comment: @Frederik: using a left handed coordinate frame might change the winding order of your primitives. Does it work when you disable blackface culling?

Comment: @DBL: I never did enable culling to begin with since it was meant for 2D. Explicitly disabling it doesn't seem to help thoug.

Comment: OK, so I stuck with the RH view matrix added a reflection matrix around the Y-axis and that seems to do the trick. Everything is pointing in the right direction. I'm going to check that camera movement and stuff like that to see that there are no oddities.

Answer (score 0):

The trick with the reflection matrix works; The orientation and position of all objects on screen works out and camera movement produces the expected results.

This page is what tipped me off on the fact that the only difference between left and right-hand view matrixes is the direction of the X-axis, and that mirroring/reflections changes the handedness:
https://www.realtimerendering.com/blog/left-handed-vs-right-handed-viewing/

That should make sense, if you compare your hands they only differ in what side the thumb is on, not in what direction the fingers are pointing.

The solution:

1. Create a standard right-handed view matrix, but define the up-vector as [0, -1, 0]
2. Create a reflection matrix that flips the view around the Y-axis:

```
[-1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0
  0, 0, 0, 1]
```

3. multiply the reflection and view matrix:
   `reflection_matrix * view_matrix;`

This works in OpenGL, but allegedly DirectX works with row-major matrices, so you have to take that into account when multiplying.

This is the code I use to produce the view matrix:

```rust
let eye: glm::Vec3 = glm::vec3(160.0, 90.0, 300.0);
let target: glm::Vec3 = glm::vec3(160.0, 90.0, 0.0);

let cam_forward = glm::normalize(&(&eye - &target));
let up = glm::Vec3::new(0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
let cam_right = glm::normalize(&glm::cross(&up, &cam_forward));
let cam_up = glm::normalize(&glm::cross(&cam_forward, &cam_right));

let mut mx_view = glm::look_at(&eye, &target, &cam_up);

let mut mirr: glm::Mat4 = glm::Mat4::identity();
mirr[0] = -1.0;

mx_view = mirr * mx_view;
```

The camera looks down the Z-axis of my 320 by 180 pixel world.

This is of-course in rust, but, based on the excellent nalgebra-glm crate which pretty closely replicates what glm does for C++, so I think anyone using C++ should also be able to follow.

Comment: It's worh noting for rust users that the nalgebra crate (not nalgebra-glm) has an Isometry3 struct that can produce the initial view matrix: nalgebra::Isometry3::look_at_rh(...). This is shorter and nicer, but I like the more manual solution because it helps me understand how all of this sits together, and for the answer it ports better to other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend changing the camera matrix.

Instead, try to use `glClipControl(GL_UPPRER_LEFT,GL_ZERO_TO_ONE)`; in this situation, the front face will be CW.

Or simply multiply the projection matrix `P[1][1]` by -1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! glClipControl was unknown to me, but setting it to GL_UPPER_LEFT flips the image upside-down around the X-axis. That could probably be fixed by rearranging the order in my element array, but then my perfectly working orthographic projection would break. I will try out the solution with negating the MVP element, but isn't that sort of what mirroring does, but before the final matrix is constructed? Is there any particular reason why it would be better to do it on the final MVP? Cheers!

Comment: @Fredrik, Sorry, my mistake, multiply the projection matrix P[1][1] by -1, not MVP. It works similar to glClipControl, flip the y coordinate in clip space. And I do not think it will break the orthographic projection.